# Midpoint rule in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

So, I am very new to the whole programming thing so any and all help is appreciated. I am trying to solve this integral using the composite midpoint rule. I know what my answer is supposed to be, and I am getting close, but it's not exactly right. My code is as follows:

```
implicit none
double precision:: a,b,dx,m,f,s,x
integer::i,n

a=1.0d0
b=2.0d0

n=6
dx=(b-a)/n

s=0.0d0
do i=0,n
s=s+f(a+i*(dx/2))
end do

print*, s*(dx)
return
end

double precision function f(x)
implicit none
double precision :: x

f=x*log(x)
return
end
```

Can anyone tell me what errors there are in this code that could be giving me the wrong answer? I think the error is in the line

```
s=s+f(a+i*(dx/2))
```

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, your loop is adding together `n+1` numbers rather than `n`. You should stop the loop at `n-1` (or maybe start at 1)

Also, the spacing between successive sample points in the midpoint rule should be what you are calling `dx`, not `dx/2`. The sample points are:

```
a + (dx/2), a + 3*(dx/2), a + 5*(dx/2), ...
```

You need to either

1) replace `i` by `(2*i+1)` in `s=s+f(a+i*(dx/2))`

or

2) Before you enter the main loop, replace `a` by `a + dx/2` (assuming that `a` is a local variable that can be reassigned without effecting the calling code -- I don't remember if Fortran is pass by value or pass by reference) and then just use the line `s=s+f(a+i*dx)`. The point is that once the first sample point is shifted to be the midpoint of the first partition piece, the midpoints of the other subinterval can be reached by steps of size `dx`.